# Java method call chaining in static context

Tags: java, static-methods, method-chaining

In StringBuilder class I can do like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append( "asd").append(34);
```

method append returns StringBuilder instance, and I can continuosly call that.

My question is it possible to do so in static method context? without class instance

Comment: What do you mean by "In StringBuilder class"- you can't edit the class

Comment: By static context do you mean to do somthing like StringBuilder.append()? If it is why would you want to do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes.  Like this (untested).

```
public class Static {

  private final static Static INSTANCE = new Static();

  public static Static doStuff(...) {
     ...;
     return INSTANCE;
  }

  public static Static doOtherStuff() {
    ....
    return INSTANCE;
  }
}
```

You can now have code like.

```
Static.doStuff(...).doOtherStuff(...).doStuff(...);
```

I would recommend against it though.

Comment: INSTANCE has to be static in this case.

Comment: @GuisongHe Care to explain?

Answer (score 5):

This is called *method-chaining*.

To do it, you always need an instantiated object.
So, sorry, but you cannot do it in a static context as there is no object associated with that.

Comment: This isn't true. I'm ashamed of this community that no one noticed it and commented in 11 years.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want this ?

```
public class AppendOperation() {
    private static StringBuilder sb =  new StringBuilder(); 

    public static StringBuilder append(String s){
        return sb.append(s);
    }

    public static void main(String... args){

         System.out.println(AppendOperation.append("ada").append("dsa").append("asd"));

    }

}
```

maybe I don't understand the question (static context) correctly

do you mean this?

static {

} //of course you can do this, too

if not all above, you can't do without any static method because append() is not static

Answer (score 1):

You want the builder pattern on a static? No. Best to convert your statics to instances.

Answer (score 1):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20823323) You can simply return `null`.
For example:

```
public class MyClass {

    public static MyClass myMethod() {
        doSomething();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's strange to return `null` . You expect it to throw a NPE, but it actually works!