# Chaining static methods

Tags: java, android

This might not have a solution, or I might have not been able to find one, but here it is:

**!! Note: the code below is incorrect, I know. I just want to show what exactly I *would like* to accomplish.**

I would like to do something on the lines:

```
public class ActionBarHandler{

    public static ActionBarHandler withAddOption(){
            //do something ...
        return ActionBarHandler;
    }
    public static ActionBarHandler withEditOption(){
           //do something ...
           return ActionBarHandler;
    }
}
```

... in order to do the below somewhere in another class (i.e. have it in a single line):

```
//..
ActionBarHandler.withAddOption().withEditOption().with........;
//..
```

... instead of doing this:

```
//..
ActionBarHandler.withAddOption();
ActionBarHandler.withEditOption();
ActionBarHandler.with........;
//..
```

Can this be done in any way? With **static** methods, without having an instance of the class.

Comment: Why do you need it to be static? Can't you configure an instance instead?

Comment: The "containing class" is `ActionBarHandler.class` (which is an expression of type `Class`), but that is likely not what you want .. since it is a *static method* there is *no* "containing instance". (In Java, a class is not a first-class object.)

Comment: I mean, the answer is: no. It's also unclear why you would want this. Do you not understand what static methods are for?

Comment: In Java, a class is ABSOLUTELY a first-class object.  It's just that that simple fact is no help here.

Comment: @DavidWallace No, a class is not a first class object. A `Class` object is [just another instance].

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do this; one of which @Sotirios has ably described.  The second way involves reflection.  But neither of them is worth it.

Comment: @DavidWallace I'm curious as to how it is possible to chain *static methods* in any meaningful way. The question literally makes no sense. The first method in the chain is going to return an instance of the class. While yes, the second call in the chain will *work* as the syntax allows it, but it's a static method ... so it has no reference to the instance returned by the first static method.

Comment: @BrianRoach Look I'm a firm member of the "never use static methods" brigade anyway, for all sorts of reasons.  He could make these methods return the class, then use `getMethod` and `invoke`.  But this would be kind of nuts, when all he's trying to do is to write in one line what can only sanely be written in three.

Comment: Do you have any scenarios that involve calling withXXX() methods after the object has been configured?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, declare the method as

```
public static ActionBarHandler withAddOption(){
```

and simply return `null`.

But I don't recommend this. Use objects with method chaining. From a conceptual standpoint, it doesn't make sense to invoke a `static` method on an instance, even less on a `null` reference. For that reason alone, you should consider refactoring your design to chain instance method invocations, ie. use objects.

Answer (score 2):

You are describing the 'fluent interface' pattern. I think the best solution would be using the 'builder' pattern. Just google 'java builder pattern' and you will find tons of articles about it. It's really hard for me to choose a single article to show you.

Comment: No, he's not. He's describing a *fluent interface*, but seemingly not understanding what static methods are for.

Comment: Fixed it. The only thing that I was wrong about was that 'he was describing the pattern'. I wasn't wrong about 'he should use the pattern' part.

Answer (score 0):

Below code shows chaining unbounded Function method references. Static references can be no harder than that.

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class TempTest {

    public static class A {
        public Void f1() { System.out.println("A.f1 called......."); return null; }
    
        public Void f2() { System.out.println("A.f2 called......."); return null; }
    
        public <T> T chain(Function<T, Void> f) { f.apply((T) this); return (T) this; }
    }
    
    public static class B extends A {
        public Void f1() { System.out.println("B.f1 called......."); return null; }
    
        public Void f3() { System.out.println("B.f3 called......."); return null; }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        new A().chain(A::f1).chain(A::f2);
        new B().chain(B::f1).chain(B::f2).chain(B::f3).chain(A::f1);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A.f1 called.......
A.f2 called.......
B.f1 called.......
A.f2 called.......
B.f3 called.......
B.f1 called.......
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class ActionBarHandler
{

    public static Class<ActionBarHandler> withAddOption(){
            //do something ...
        return ActionBarHandler.class;
    }
    public static Class<ActionBarHandler> withEditOption(){
           //do something ...
           return ActionBarHandler.class;
    }
}
```

Comment: `ActionBarHandler.withAddOption().withEditOption()` will not work (`can not resolve method withEditOption in Class`).